# input elements and combo boxes are not accessible

Tags: bing-maps

im trying to use an infobox in bing-map V7 with inputs and combo boxes, but i cant access the 'input' and 'select' elements with a "click" probably because of bing-map default handlers? Any help for a work around is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a work around use the custom infobox control: https://bingmapsv7modules.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Infobox%20Control This module provides a much more customizable infobox control for Bing Maps where customer HTML content works a lot better.